# Cannot read property "name" of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of an odd "bug" (quotations because it's not breaking anything, it's just an error in the console).

I have a website that simulates a retail website. When you click on an item, a div pops up asking you if you want to add it to the cart. If you press confirm, it sends the products name and price to a function that adds it to a EasyUI datagrid, as seen here:

Checking if product has been clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
        if (ismobile) {
            price = $(this).find('p.title').attr("data");
            name = $(this).find('p.title').html();
            image = $(this).find('img').attr("src");            

            mobileproducts(price, name, image);
        }
    });
```

Checking if"Add to cart" has been clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', "#mob_add", function() {
        name = $(".mob_title").html();
        //price = $(".mob_price").html();

        addProduct(name, parseFloat(price));
        console.log(name + parseFloat(price));
        $("#popup").hide();
    });
```

And the function where it adds it to a Datagrid (the cart).

```
function addProduct(name, price) {
    function add(){
        for (var i=0; i<data.total; i++) {
            var row = data.rows[i];
            if(row.name == name) {             ** ERROR HAPPENS ON THIS LINE **
                row.quantity++;
                return;
            }
        }
        data.total++;
        data.rows.push({
            name:name,
            quantity:1,
            price:price
        });
    }
    add();
    ...
}
```

Now as I've mentioned, this works perfectly fine, no problems. The item gets added to the cart, and if there's more than one of that item, the item quantity gets increased. 
This also works fine if you drag the product to the cart instead of clicking on it, printing no errors.

A demo can be seen [here](http://davidpuetter.azurewebsites.net/shop.html#/): (note, to click on a product, window must be < 900px width, drag and drop needs window to be > 900px)

What I want to know is, why this error is happening.

**EDIT:** I've also found that, when you first load the page and add a product, no error is printed, but adding a product after that, causes an error. Also happens if you reload the page, open a product dialog, close it without adding to the cart, and then adding any product to the cart.

Comment: What are you asking? How do I replicate the error?

Comment: I'm curious why your getting 'data.rows[i]' but your checking i against data.total.  It seems like you should be checking against data.rows.length

Comment: In the first function, none of your variables are declared. How does that not fall over immediately?

Comment: I'm asking why this error is happening. 
@Taplar , I'm comparing the content of the row # and column "name" with the item I'm adding, to see if there's any alike.

Comment: You can replicate the error by making the window smaller than 900px then clicking on a product, and adding it to the cart.

Comment: If your i index is not in the confines of the array you are applying it against, it will return a null.  and you'll get a null pointer error if you try to do .name off of it.

Comment: add `console.log(data)` before the error line, what do you get?

Comment: With all those global variables, if your site isn't broken at the moment, it will be eventually.

Comment: I tried printing name just before the error line and it prints the correct product name, so that part should work fine.

Comment: `name` is not precisely reserved, but its use should be avoided.  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: You are binding multiple click event handlers onto the button every time the `mobileproducts` method is called. I would refactor to bind the function only once on the button, but then the function should use correct variables to follow through with the addition method calls. Additionally, instead of binding on `document` using a selector would it be possible to bind directly on the button?

Comment: @squint Looking at your tags (JS :), I wanted to ask what's you opinion on using `on` with `document` ? I feel it would probably be inefficient causing JQuery to trigger on every click within the window and filtering via selector (unless I'm wrong).....

Comment: I've bound the `on()` to their nearest parent now :) I guess it would be more efficient?

Comment: @maythesource.com: I don't use jQuery any more but I would be inclined against any highly generalized event delegation system being rooted at the document level. If required, I'd roll my own to fit the circumstance. You?

Comment: @squint I only hack stuff when needed frontend side but I always bound directly on the element in JQuery. Finally, now using Angular so I never access the dom directly or use JQuery that much. What have you moved to for front end scripting?

Comment: @maythesource.com: I have my own micro library. IMO, large abstractions like jQuery aren't worth their download and performance cost, assuming IE6/7 don't need to be supported. I've written my own server framework as well, so there's a little integration between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After helpful comments and necessary downvotes I looked at the debugger again.
It seems that using the dialog causes one extra iteration over the products ( and the last row is undefined).

There may be a chance that you are calling the `add()` function two times.

**Update:**

Using firefox I saved the webpage (using complete) temporarily on my local drive.

I noticed that the function handling the click event for add (in the dialog) shows my alert `test` two times instead of one.

```
$(document).on('click', "#mob_add", function() {
        name = $(".mob_title").html();
        //price = $(".mob_price").html();

    alert("TEST"); // Should run only once
    addProduct(name, parseFloat(price));
    console.log(name + parseFloat(price));
    $("#popup").hide();
});
```

**Update:**
You are re-using the same dialog and are re-adding continuously new click handlers to the `document` object using a selector.

If `mobileproducts` is called every time the dialog appears, an additional click handler is binded every time.

```
    function mobileproducts(price, name, image) {
        $("#popup").show();
        $(".mob_title").html(name);
        $("#popup > img").attr("src", image);
        $(".mob_price").html("£" + price);


        $(document).on('click', "#mob_close", function() {
                $("#popup").hide();


    });
     alert('binding again');
        $(document).on('click', "#mob_add", function() {
            name = $(".mob_title").html();
        //price = $(".mob_price").html();

        alert("TEST");
        addProduct(name, parseFloat(price));
        console.log(na

me + parseFloat(price));
            $("#popup").hide();
        });

        console.log("CLICKED: " + name + " WITH PRICE: " + price + " AND IMAGE URL: " + image);
    }
```

### Fix

The quickest fix would be to stop binding first on document, and switch to using the popup (or even the button). Additionally, before finding a new function, you should unbind the previous.

Working example below:

```
function mobileproducts(price, name, image) {
    $("#popup").show();
    $(".mob_title").html(name);
    $("#popup > img").attr("src", image);
    $(".mob_price").html("£" + price);
    //alert("TEST2");

    $("#popup").unbind('click');

    $("#popup").on('click', "#mob_close", function() {
        $("#popup").hide();
    });
    $("#popup").on('click', "#mob_add", function() {
        name = $(".mob_title").html();
        //price = $(".mob_price").html();


        addProduct(name, parseFloat(price));
        console.log(name + parseFloat(price));
        $("#popup").hide();
    });

    console.log("CLICKED: " + name + " WITH PRICE: " + price + " AND IMAGE URL: " + image);
}
```

A better fix would be to even BIND only once using `on`, and refactor your code to use singleton parameters that are available to that function.

Comment: Never heard of `unbind()`. Thank you! This works fine. Now, do you have an idea why the code technically still worked, it just decided to print an error? :P

Comment: Yes. Imagine every time you click a product, you were binding again and again on the document. However, since on the click it ran successfully for the currently selected product, it had no effect if all the other binded functions failed. Also, I suspect the `undefined` error stopped the execution of the upcoming errors. Imagine creating a new anonymous function every time a product is clicked... so after 10 product clicks you have 10 anonymous functions running on click... the first works, the second crashes, and the other 8 never run due to the crash.

Comment: Thank squint...she/he reigned me in to dig deeper :D . Also continuously binding+unbind is sort of a hack... if you feel like it look into binding once, and modifying code to use something like a global datastructure (or module) to handle params. Global variables are frowned upon... (things can be over-written etc). See something like: https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/